# how to restart a program when detects it is down without knowing root?

Tags: c, linux

I write a program, in c language. This program will ssh to another computer and touch a file periodically. However, sometimes the program crashes. How to restart this c program automatically when it crashes ? I know we can use cron job to do this, but I am not root, I don't know the password, too. I cannot access to /etc/init.d, too. It is on linux .

Comment: It would probably be better to find out why your program crashes, and fix that instead.

Comment: Many reasons. Sometimes administer restart that computer.

Comment: You don't have to be root to add a cron job to your own crontab.

Comment: Have you tried using cron?  On CentOs 6 each user has their own crontab they can edit.  Try `crontab -e`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. I thought cron job must be root......

Comment: It used to be like that (a long time ago)  But both Linux and FreeBSD have user crontabs now.

Comment: New program: `/* ... */ for (;;) system("originalprogram"); /* ... */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use a crontab job to ensure that a program runs. [Here's](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) a quick introduction/reference. You do not need root access to create your own crontab job.